# How to traverse all the tr elements with in the table using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

how to traverse all tr to give values in td.In my code it is overriding same tr/td.

My table.

```
#qty to add
<tbody id="gridview-1161-body">
<tr id="gridview-1161-record-19842148" data-boundview="gridview-1161" class="x-grid-row x-grid-data-row" tabindex="-1">
<td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1158  rp-grid-editable-cell  rp-grid-editable-cell" id="ext-gen2535">
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
<div class="rp-invalid-cell rp-icon-alert-require-field">
</div>
<input id="numberfield-1243-inputEl" type="text" role="spinbutton" name="Quantity" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-focus x-field-form-focus x-field-default-form-focus" autocomplete="off" style="width: 100%;"> 
</div></td>
</tr>

same like 
<tr>..</tr></tbody>
```

Here all the id's are dynamically generating via code.
My python code:

```
#add qty
    rowCount=len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody[@id='gridview-1161-body']/tr"));
    print(rowCount)
    for row in rowCount:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.x-grid-cell.x-grid-td.rp-grid-editable-cell[role='gridcell']")))
        element.click()
        time.sleep(2)

        #input box to give qty-working for this id
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "numberfield-1243-inputEl").send_keys('10')
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "numberfield-1243-inputEl").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

due to dynamic id i can't give find_element(By.ID)So i am using CSS_SELECTOR to find the td,but it is overriding same td..how to give tr.next to traverse all tr in table ?

Comment: take all `tr` in list and iterate it then do `list[0].find_element(td)`

Comment: i have many td inside single tr. @Dev

Comment: get those `td` of every `tr` in list and iterate that list as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle dynamic ID Induce `WebDriverWait()` and `visibility_of_all_elements_located`()
and Following `XPATH` option.

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
rows=WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//tbody[contains(@id,'-body')]//tr[@class='x-grid-row x-grid-data-row']")))
for rownum in range(len(rows)):

     #To avoid stale exception re-assign rows elements again
     rows = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody[contains(@id,'-body')]//tr[@class='x-grid-row x-grid-data-row']")))
     element=rows[rownum].find_element_by_xpath(".//td[contains(@class,'rp-grid-editable-cell  rp-grid-editable-cell') and @role='gridcell']")
     element.click()
     input=rows[rownum].find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@name='Quantity' and @role='spinbutton']")
     input.send_keys('10')
     input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: @DivyaMani : Can you please share your url if possible.This code should work for each row unless anything changed.

Comment: element=rows[rownum].find_element_by_xpath(".//td[contains(@class,'rp-grid-editable-cell  rp-grid-editable-cell') and @role='gridcell']")
IndexError: list index out of range  this is what i'm getting from second iteration.Please help me to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Get all rows, then find child `td` and `input`:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

rows = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr[id*='-record-'].x-grid-data-row")))
for row in rows:
    row.find_element_by_css_selector("td[role='gridcell']").click()
    row.find_element_by_name("Quantity").send_keys("10", Keys.ENTER)
```

Second way with xpath and index:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
row_locator = "(//tr[contains(@id,'-record-')])"
rows_len = len(wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, row_locator))))
for i in range(1, rows_len + 1):
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"{row_locator}[{i}]/td[@role='gridcell']"))).click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"{row_locator}[{i}]/input[@name='Quantity']").send_keys("10", Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: rows = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr[id*='-record-'].x-grid-data-row")))
  File "C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: even after loading this page im getting timeout error.

Comment: Try it with `presence_of_all_elements_located`. Check updated code

Comment: row.find_element_by_css_selector("td[role='gridcell']").click()    
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: Try second code with xpath with `element_to_be_clickable` or remove click

Answer (score 0):

To traverse all the child `<input>` tags with in the ancestor `<tr>` tags to send *character sequence* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
for element in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody[starts-with(@id, 'gridview') and contains(@id, '-body')]/tr/td//input[@name='Quantity' and starts-with(@id, 'numberfield-')]"))):
    element.send_keys('10')
    element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```